# AngularJS-How to access variables inside an array of objects using ng repeat after server's response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having a hard time using ng-repeat to access variables inside an array of objects that i get from the server. My code is as follows:

**Controller**

```
vm.getcategories = function () {

         vm.categories = CategoryService.get();
         vm.index = 0;
         vm.array = [];
         vm.names=[];
         vm.pictures=[]         
         vm.counter=0;

         for (var i = 0; i < vm.categories.length; i++){
              vm.names.push(vm.categories[i].name);
              vm.pictures.push(vm.categories[i].category_number)
            };


         for (var i = 0; i < vm.categories.length / 2; i++){
             vm.array.push(i); }
           return true;

     };
```

**HTML**

```
    <h1 class="header">{{'CATEGORY'|translate}}</h1><br>
<div ng-controller="CategoriesController as catCtrl" class="category-content" >
     <table class="table-content" class="category-content" ng-show="catCtrl.getcategories()">
        <tr ng-repeat="i in catCtrl.array track by $index"  ng-init="index = i*2">
            <td layout-align="space-around center" ng-repeat="category in catCtrl.categories.slice(index,index+2)" >

                <md-button a href="#!subcategory" md-whiteframe="6" ng-click="catCtrl.submit(category.category_number)" class="category-button"  aria-label="{{category}}">
                    <div class="category-button-text-translation">{{name|uppercase| translate}}</div>
                    <img img ng-repeat="picture in catCtrl.pictures" ng-src="assets/images/categories/{{picture}}.png" alt="{{picture}}">
                    <div class="category-button-text-english">"{{name|lowercase}}"</div>
                </md-button>
                <span flex></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Each object in the array looks like

```
{ category_number: "***",
  type:            "****",
  id:              "******"
}
```

The objects are categories and I want to repeat over the categories and also access their keys at the same time. I tried filling up all the arrays after the server's response just like in my controller and having a different ng repeat on every data type but that doesn't work. So I was thinking, seeing my data structure is it possible that I access type and picture from the array of objects and use it in my view? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

My expected response is :

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "data": {
    "categories": [

      {
        "_id": "5978bfc7c405bc5c9cb1fbef",
        "category_number": "101",
        "name": "Services"
      }
    ]
  },
  "message": "successful",
  "status": "success"
}
```

And my CategoryService.get() looks like:

```
get : function(){
            var accessdata=window.localStorage['categories']
            var stored=JSON.parse(accessdata)
          return stored;
           },
```

I get the data from local storage. The data is added to local storage from http request in another view.

Comment: post your json to see the structure

Comment: i see that you have a service CategoryService i dont know if is a promis inc ase is a promise all other code must bien inside success promise response otherwise vmcategories maybe undefined.

Comment: Post the function `get` in the `CategoryService` service, please

Comment: I updated my post, if you could see. Thanks!

Comment: You are doing far too many calculations in the HTML. Move those calculations into the controller. It will be easier to debug, test, and maintain.